# Part Replace multiple words using Regex

Tags: regex

I want to process lots of files as part of Post Migration of our code. The Migration Tool can handle RegEx and we write something like below:
'# Replace ".Columns(", ".Columns.Item("
This replaces all occurances of ".Columns(" with ".Columns.Item(".

As one of our requirement I want to Replace NullString word with double quotes i.e. ""
E.g. Optional ByVal strID2 As String = NullString 
should become 
Optional ByVal strID2 As String = ""

This is required as the NullString in VB6 is now becoming a class variable and in Function declaration it needs to be a constant.
So, I need a RegEx with one of the criteria below:

1. Make sure its in Function Declaration i.e. Has Word "Function" then its name and opens a  bracket "(". Then any occurrences of [= NullString] should be replaced with [= ""] till we hit closing bracket ")", as the declaration could be on multiple line.
2. Just see if its Optional parameter. So match word "Optional" then "As String = NullString" and replace NullString with "".

I can use one of the 2 as criteria but unable to write a RegEx. Below is my sample file and I've explained what I want for each line.

---

### **My sammple file contents**

***Line 1***:`Public Function getAllAddresses(ByVal lngObjectType As String, ByVal strID1 As String, Optional ByVal strID2 As String = NullString, Optional ByVal strID3 As String = NullString, Optional ByVal blnExtraAddresses As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef objDataRequest As CDataRequest = Nothing) As ADORecordset`

***Line 2***:Dim s as String

***Line 3***:`s = NullString`

***Line 4*** (Blank):

***Line 5***:`Public Function getDefaultPaymentAddress(ByVal lngObjectType As Integer, ByVal strID1 As String, ByVal strID2 As String, Optional ByRef objDataRequest As CDataRequest = Nothing) As typAddress`

***Line 6***:`Public Function myfunc(Optional ByVal strID2 As String = NullString, _`

***Line 7***:                  `Optional ByVal strID3 As String = NullString, _`

***Line 8***:                  `Optional ByVal blnExtraAddresses As Boolean = False, _`

***Line 9***:                  `Optional ByRef objDataRequest As CDataRequest = Nothing) As String`

***Line 10***:`'Some code comments with = NullString`

***More Lines*** till end of file:

---

Expected ***Output*** for each line:

1. **Line 1**: Being a big line just output the whole declaration with NullString replaced with quotes i.e. "".
2. **Line 2**: As it is
3. **Line 3**: As it is [*Notice that NullString should not be replaced*]
4. **Line 4**: As it is i.e. Blank
5. **Line 5**: As it is. There is no NullString here so not a match
6. **Line 6 to 9**: 2 NullString replaced by double quotes (Line 6 and 7)
7. **Line 10**: As it is. This is just a comment.

   I might have something like `If myVar = NullString Then`, but it should not be matched and replaced.
   Thanks in Advance for the help.
   Regards,
   Nik

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make all the changes with one regex.

You could try the following:

```
' Repeat this until there are no more changes.
Search: (Function +\w+ *\([^)]*?)\bNullString\b
Replace: $1""

' Use a multiline match for this one.
Search: ^([ \t]*\w+ *= *)NullString\b
Replace: $1""
```

Comment: Hmmm... so I dont know how many lines I need to write :-(

May be 10? and assume that it'll take care of most of my functions. But it may slow down my migration process as it'll run on more than 1000 files and 10000+ lines of code.